# How database naming for items work in CakePHP?

Tags: php, database, cakephp, naming

I am learning PHP along with the lib CakePHP.
I want to know how CakePHP names the items added to the db using the `add()` method?

I read some pages about the convention of naming in CakePHP but could not understand much. To give you an example about naming:

Let's say I have some items associated with some people and I have tables for people as well as the items. In my app, I choose a person and I add a item to that person. In the items table, I want the filename column value of that item to be:

`<personname>_<itemname>_<numberoftheitem>_<date>`

How do I configure that naming in CakePHP? 
and there is an initialize() function for components, maybe is that the place for that kind of configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table class names are plural, CamelCased and end in Table. UsersTable, ArticleCategoriesTable, and UserFavoritePagesTable are all examples of conventional model names.

Table names corresponding to CakePHP models are plural and underscored. The underlying tables for the above mentioned models would be users, article_categories, and user_favorite_pages, respectively.

The convention is to use English words for table and column names. If you use words in another language, CakePHP might not be able to process the right inflections (from singular to plural and vice-versa).

Field names with two or more words are underscored: first_name.

Cake's naming conventions use id for primary keys. For foreign keys use _id prefixed with the singular snake cased related table name.

Foreign keys in hasMany, belongsTo/hasOne relationships are recognized by default as the (singular) name of the related table followed by _id. So if Users hasMany Articles, the articles table will refer to the users table via a user_id foreign key. For a table like article_categories whose name contains multiple words, the foreign key would be article_category_id.

Join tables, used in BelongsToMany relationships between models, should be named after the model tables they will join, arranged in alphabetical order (articles_tags rather than tags_articles).

You can read up more on Cake's naming conventions in the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html).

Answer (score 0):

See @RavK answer.

To set a property value you can use this method in entity

```
public function _setFilename($filename)
{
    return $this->person->name . '_' . $this->itemname . '_' . $this->numberoftheitem . '_' . $this->date;
}
```

Notice that you need the person/people contained in the entity, or you have to do a db query to get the name.

Edit: Don't know where you get itemname, numberoftheitem and data, but I assumes it is a property in your entity (table column).